# Laravel: Run Artisan Commands in Parallel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run artisan commands simultaneously in parallel, here is my code:

```
$files = glob($this->fixedDir . '*.csv');

foreach ($files as $csvFile) {
   Artisan::call('mycommand:import', ['--file' =>$csvFile]);
}
```

So idea is to pass file option and then each commands handles that. However above code runs each command sequentially not in parallel. I also tried like this:

```
$schedule = new Schedule();
$files = glob($this->fixedDir . '*.csv');

foreach ($files as $csvFile) {
   $schedule->command('mycommand:import', ['--file' =>$csvFile])
   ->everyMinute()
   ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

Even that didn't seem to work.

Can somebody tell how do I run commands in parallel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use Jobs and Queues for this.

```
php artisan make:job ImportCsv
```

Then edit your job class to process your csv file import. Then dispatch this job from a controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\ImportCsv;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FileController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Store a new file.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Create file...

    dispatch(new ImportCsv($file));
}
}
```

Make sure your worker process is running. You can start it like this:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

You can learn details from documentation; [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ServeWebsocketsAndQueue extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'serve:wq';

    protected $description = 'Start the Laravel server, WebSockets server, npm dev, and queue listener in parallel';

    protected $pids = []; // Store process IDs (PIDs)

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Starting Laravel server, WebSockets server, npm dev, and queue listener in parallel...');

        // Fork processes to run commands in parallel
        $commands = [
            'php artisan serve',
            'php artisan queue:listen',
            'npm run dev'
        ];

        foreach ($commands as $command) {
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if ($pid == -1) {
                // Fork failed
                $this->error("Failed to fork for command: $command");
            } elseif ($pid) {
                // Parent process
                $this->pids[] = $pid;
            } else {
                // Child process
                exec($command);
                exit(); // Exit child process
            }
        }

        // Wait for signals to stop the commands
        pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function ($signal) {
            $this->info("Received signal to stop. Stopping child processes...");
            $this->stopCommands();
        });

        // Wait for all child processes to finish
        foreach ($this->pids as $pid) {
            pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
        }
    }

    protected function stopCommands()
    {
        // Send SIGINT signal to child processes
        foreach ($this->pids as $pid) {
            posix_kill($pid, SIGINT);
        }
    }
}
```

add your commands in `$commands = [];` and change the signature ( `protected $signature = 'serve:wq';`) to whatever you want
use: `php artisan serve:wq` to run all the commands from array in parallel.